# Creating child items for listviewitem in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<ListViewItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Images/running.png"/>
                <TextBlock> RUN </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
</ListViewItem>
```

I have set my listview to be outputed like this now I want to add this kind hierarchy from my C# code, but listview item does not let me set it's child items.

Comment: Please provide more details. do you get an error? What is your C# code looking like?

Comment: Do you want to create the same "structure" (that you declared using XAML) by using code (C#)?

Comment: Yes I want the same structure from C# to create listviewItem and its Child elements (in this case StackPanel, Image and TextBlock). So I'm wondering if it's even possible in wpf to give ListViewItem the child elements.